# Sails.js: Enable some (but not all) REST blueprint routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, controller, sails.js

In Sails.js v0.10, I can set whether or not to expose REST routes for controllers by setting the `rest` property in `config\blueprints.js` or by setting `_config: { rest: true } //or false` in the controller definition.

Does anyone know if it's possible (and how) to set this for some REST routes but not all?

For example, something like `rest: { find: true, create: true, destroy: false, update: false }`

I realize there are workarounds, but it would be nice to be able to set the defaults in one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use policy setting like below.
this will allow find but disable the other method.

```
'Foo': {
    '*': false,
    'find': 'sessionAuth'
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the workaround I'm using and seems like the best way.  It's not so bad, but I would really like to see something like what I proposed.  Guess I'll take it github.

Answer (score -1):

you can duplicate the default blueprint api and remove unwanted js files and in your routing bind the routes to the specific custom blueprint you made.
it will work